# Is it possible to use search.luceneSearch with previously declared vars?

Tags: javascript, lucene, alfresco

I want to create a script which will be validated by an action/folder rule in Share.

I was thinking about using previously declared vars, something like these:

```
var clientsite = "client"
var docfolder = "document_alias"
var docyear = 2015
```

And my code would be something like this:

```
var folder = search.luceneSearch(" PATH:\"/app:company_home/st:sites/**clientsite**/**docfolder** \" AND TYPE:\"cm:folder\" AND \@cm\\:name:\"**docyear**\" ");
if (folder == null || folder.length == 0) {
//create new folder called 'docyear' 
} 
else { 
//move to the already existing folder related to 'docyear'
}
```

Where the **bold(I tried to bold items with * in the code, sorry)** values would be the vars previously declared.

Is there a way to use vars like in that way??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sure! You just need to append them, the standard javascript string creation doesn't support template parameters, so take your line

```
var folder = search.luceneSearch(" PATH:\"/app:company_home/st:sites/**clientsite**/**docfolder** \" AND TYPE:\"cm:folder\" AND \@cm\\:name:\"**docyear**\" ");
```

And make it something like

```
var folder = search.luceneSearch(" PATH:\"/app:company_home/st:sites/"+clientsite+"/"+docfolder+" \" AND TYPE:\"cm:folder\" AND \@cm\\:name:\""+docyear+"\" ");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Gagravarr !

I can keep the var clientsite = "client"? What you mean to append is just add "+ between the desired var? 

Because it returned ReferenceError: "clientsite" is not defined.
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! It's everything fine now. I realised also that I can use childbynamePath to check the existence of folders.